# How do I use `sudo -e` together with gvim?

Tags: sudo, vim, text-editor

So when one edits a file owned by root it is recommended to use `sudo -e`. This will open a copy of the file in your favorite `$EDITOR`. Using this together with vim works like a charm.

However, when I want to use the graphical variant, i.e. gvim, it will open an empty file, and the sudo command returns directly, stating that nothing was changed.

Is there a way to make this work?

Comment: Try `sudo -H gvim filename`

Comment: Well that works, but how does it differ from `sudo gvim filename`?

Comment: Graphical editors and `sudo` don't play nice when it comes to setting the users home directory so the `-H` helps `sudo` handle this. We also have the `gksudo` graphical command version of `sudo`. See `man sudo`

Comment: See https://superuser.com/questions/202676/sudo-vs-gksudo-difference

Comment: Yeah, but then again, I don't really want my editor to run with root permissions. This is the reason behind using `sudo -e` instead of just `sudo $EDITOR filename`, right? Is that not possible with gvim?

Comment: My brother if you run with `sudo` then your obviously dealing with files owned by root or another user ( in some cases) so simply run that graphic editor like `gvim filename`, again if you notice running with `-H` will retain the original ownership of the file rather than changing it to root ownership if not owned by root originally